# ASP.NET MVC JQuery-UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

I have problem with jquery autocomplete method. Always I get this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function".

What I'm doing wrong, below my code:
_Layout.cshtml:
in head section:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

in end of body section:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

and script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#somevalue').autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("Index","Search")'
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your generating duplicate scripts. Many of the same scripts that you include in the layout are then repeated in the at the end of the body, and in particular your final `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` is including `jquery-{version}.js` for the 3rd time, and by including it last, it wipes out all the previous scripts that rely on jquery (including `jquery-ui`).

Include the scripts only one, and in the correct order. And I recommend some consistency and follow one convention, for example, place all your scripts immediately before the closing `</body>` tag (except `modernizr` which needs to be in the head), and use bundles for all your scripts.